# @Autowired Spring service is null in Play Framework 2.6 application

Tags: spring, javabeans, autowired, playframework-2.6

I'm refactoring an application from Play Framework 2.2.x to Play Framework 2.6.x, and in the updated version of the app an @Autowired spring service is null (I didn't use "new" so that Spring would be confused).

AuthentecatedAction class:

```
@Scope("prototype")
@Component
public class AuthenticatedAction extends Action<Authenticated>
{
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    ABCUserService ABCUserService;

    @Autowired
    AccessTokenService accessTokenService;

    @Autowired
    AccessTokenValidator accessTokenValidator;

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> call(Http.Context ctx)
    {
            AccessToken accessToken;
            try {
                accessToken = accessTokenService.getAccessTokenFromHeader(ctx._requestHeader().headers());
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                return ResultUtils.handleError(new ValidationException(FORBIDDEN, String.format("Access token service is null. %s", throwable.getMessage())));
            }
// Some more code here
    }
// Some more code here
}
```

Here `accessTokenService` is @Autowired, but it is always null.

AccessTokenService class:

```
@Service
public class AccessTokenService extends JedisBaseService
{
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurationService configurationService;

    @Autowired
    private EncryptionService encryptionService;

    @Inject
    public AccessTokenService(JedisPool jedisPool) {
        super(jedisPool);
    }

// some methods 

}
```

JedisBaseService class:

```
    public class JedisBaseService extends Controller
    {
        private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

        private JedisPool jedisPool;

        @Inject
        public JedisBaseService(JedisPool jedisPool) {
            this.jedisPool = jedisPool;
        }

// some methods

        // TODO: Check that solution with iserting JedisPool works
        // See https://github.com/playframework/play-plugins/tree/master/redis for reference
        protected Jedis getJedis()
        {
            return jedisPool.getResource();
        }

    }
```

Please, help me understand why @Autowired in AuthentecatedAction class `accessTokenService` is always null.

EDIT:

I should probably add, that my `build.sbt` file contains the line:

```
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context
  "org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "4.3.10.RELEASE"
```

My `routes` file contains following lines:

```
POST          /accesstokens        @api.controller.accesstoken.AccessTokenController.createAccessToken()
DELETE        /accesstokens        @api.controller.accesstoken.AccessTokenController.deleteAccessToken()
```

So, I use dynamic controller dispatching to manage controller instances (by prefixing a controller class name with the @ symbol in the routes file).

There is a controller for access tokens:

```
    @Controller
    public class AccessTokenController extends ABCController
    {
        @Autowired
        private AccessTokenService accessTokenService;

        @Autowired
        private ABCUserService ABCUserService;

        @Autowired
        private ActivityCreationService activityCreationService;

        @Autowired
        private LiveUpdateService liveUpdateService;

        @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.TolerantJson.class)
        @ResponseContentType(type = "accessToken")
        public Result createAccessToken() throws ABCControllerException
        {
// Implementation
        }

        public Result deleteAccessToken() throws ABCControllerException
        {
// Implementation
        }
    }
```

Global object of my application that delegates controller instances management:

```
public class ABCGlobal
{
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    protected static ApplicationContext ctx;

    private final ActorSystem system;

    @Inject
    public ABCGlobal(ActorSystem system) {
        this.system = system;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext()
    {
        return ctx;
    }

    public void onStart(Application app)
    {
        String springConfigurationName = app.configuration().getString("spring.context");
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfigurationName);
        log.info("Loading spring configuration: {}", springConfigurationName);

        // Some other code
    }

    // see: http://typesafe.com/blog/announcing-play-framework-21-the-high-velocit
    public <A> A getControllerInstance(Class<A> clazz)
    {
        return ctx.getBean(clazz);
    }

    // Some other code
}
```

Here is the associated conf/components.xml file that is used to configure Spring:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="api, service"/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application-base.conf" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.conf" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ServiceLocatorFactoryBean" id="resourceConverterFactory">
        <property name="serviceLocatorInterface" value="service.resource.conversion.ResourceConverterFactory">
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ServiceLocatorFactoryBean" id="scraperFactory">
        <property name="serviceLocatorInterface" value="service.scraping.ScraperFactory">
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="storageService" class="service.storage.impl.MongoGridFSStorageService"/>
    <bean id="configurationService" class="service.configuration.impl.PlayConfigurationService">
    <constructor-arg value="com.typesafe.config.Config" name="config">
    </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="mailService" class="service.mail.impl.MailGunApiMailService"/>
</beans>
```

And in my `application-base.conf` file I have the following:

```
# Spring configuration
# ~~~~~
# Define what spring context should be used.
spring.context="components.xml"
```

Comment: How do set up spring context ? before the application starts?

Comment: @zakaria-amine I have added configuration details to the question above.